# UICollectionView: How to set row height dynamically depending upon text length

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using KDCalendarView class to display calendar in my project. Now I want to show some data on each date. But for every date there could be some possible values coming from server. Now I am able to increase width and height for each item in sizeForItemAtIndexPath. But the issue here is that it sets size for each item individually. But what i need to do is depending upon 7 consecutive values I have to set max od them as height of the row not just item.

[image]

As shown in the image, in first row 0 height of date 2 item should be the height of full row not just that particular item.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (!self.displayMonthDate) {
        return 0;
}
NSInteger numberOfDaysPlusOffset = _numberOfDaysInMonth + _firstWeekdayOfMonthIndex;
NSInteger remainingDaysToFillCalendar = 7 - (numberOfDaysPlusOffset % 7);
return numberOfDaysPlusOffset + remainingDaysToFillCalendar;
}

- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
       viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind
                             atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//Used for each cell to draw
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//Setting item size here
}
```

Comment: One way is that you can find Max height in 7 column and then return the max height out of 7 for first row. and when your Row changes find max height for next 7 column and return this.

Comment: I am also thinking on this note but I thought whether there is any other possible way for achieving this.

Comment: @Arti why not use the updated version? I hope you saw that on the KDCalendar repository, its clearly said -> *This repository will not be actively maintained for much longer* and the last time it was updated was 8 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use: `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize`